# mshtml and CLS-compliance

Tags: mshtml, cls-compliant, microsoft.mshtml

I am witnessing some odd behaviour with mshtml and CLS-compliance.

I have an assembly marked CLSCompliant(true). This assembly does **not** expose any types from mshtml publicly.

I can make the code conform to CLS fairly easily, but several things seem to break it:

1. Introducing a "using mshtml;" statement instead of referencing the namespace manually each time I use a type. For some reason, this breaks CLS compliance.
2. If I convert the following:

   ```
       var doc = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;

       var scriptNode = doc.createElement("SCRIPT") as mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement;

       var nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("head");

       foreach (var head in nodes)
       {
           var htmlHead = (mshtml.HTMLHeadElement)head;
           if (htmlHead != null)
               htmlHead.appendChild((mshtml.IHTMLDOMNode)scriptNode);
       }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
       foreach (var head in nodes.OfType<mshtml.IHTMLDOMNode>())
           head.appendChild((mshtml.IHTMLDOMNode)scriptNode);
   ```

   This also seems to break CLS compliance.

Can anyone offer any insight as to what might be going on here?  Because for me, none of this breaks CLS compliance.

PS When I say breaks CLS compliance, 167 warnings are raised about each type in the mshtml namespace that begins with an underscore, or similar CLS violations.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't and just stuck with the earlier version.

Comment: thanks changing to mshtml.IHTMLDOMNode solved my problem!

Comment: A stab in the dark would be that its embedding some interop types which are then part of the referencing assembly, thus anything embedded that violates CLS compliance will violate it in the built referencing assembly.