# mshtml cls-compliant unknown warnings

Tags: c#, .net, warnings, mshtml, cls-compliant

I have a .net project written in C#. There is only 1 class in the project that uses the Microsoft.mshtml library, however there are 2 classes in the project that are generating mshtml warnings on build. Here are a couple of examples of the warnings:

```
Identifier 'mshtml._BEHAVIOR_EVENT_FLAGS' is not CLS-compliant
Identifier 'mshtml.__MIDL___MIDL_itf_mshtml_0250_0001' is not CLS-compliant
```

I'm getting pretty much a duplicate of 162 different warnings in the 2 classes that are complaining about mshtml identifiers that I never use. These 2 classes never use or reference Microsoft.mshtml. I've gone to the debugging point of removing all code from one of the classes and all references to the class in code and I still get the warnings. I found a similar post on stack overflow here:

[mshtml and CLS-compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456256/mshtml-and-cls-compliance)

That never got an answer. Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Comment: This mattered a decade ago.  Today, meh.  Just use [assembly:CLSCompliant(false)] and move on with your life.